# Why is my Receive-Job call hanging when calling a scriptblock?

Tags: powershell

My code can't reach the final output line:

```
$downloadCommand = { 
    $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$someurl" -OutFile "$somelocation" 
    0 
}

$job = Start-Job $downloadCommand

$sleeptime=10

While(Get-Job -State "Running")
{
    #Get-Job -State "Running"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $sleeptime
}

Get-Job | Wait-Job

$result = Receive-Job -Job $job # <=== gets stuck here

Write-Host "Can't reach here"
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I know the download is working fine and it certainly gets out of the while loop.

Comment: Could you please define or elaborate on `get's stuck here`? Is the script executing continuously at that point or what's happening?

Comment: The script just hangs and keeps executing continuously until I kill it.

Comment: Is the file at `$somelocation` being created/written? If not, try changing the `Invoke-WebRequest` invocation to `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$someurl" -OutFile "$somelocation" -UseBasicParsing`

Comment: Yes, the file gets written/downloaded to that location successfully. It's a 180 MB zip file. When I comment out the line that gets stuck, the rest of my script continues and I can unzip this file.

For what it's worth, I run the powershell script this way (called from a .bat script):


`powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command C:\foo.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, I can't get your example to hang infinitely. Maybe you are downloading some huge file? Maybe your destination server is processing indefinitely?

I've modified your script to get more info.

If you are checking the job state and waiting with `Start-Sleep` - there is no need for Wait-Job in your script.

Proper way to wait for job:

```
$downloadCommand = { 
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$someurl" -OutFile "$somelocation";
}

$job = Start-Job $downloadCommand;
    
$sleepTime = 10;

while ((Get-Job | Where-Object Id -eq $job.Id).State -eq "Running")
{
    Write-Host "Waiting next $sleepTime seconds for job $($job.Id) to finish...";
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $sleepTime;
}

Receive-Job $job;
```

BTW since Powershell 7.0 - you can use Foreach-Object -Parallel (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7)

Comment: It's a 180 MB zip file. 

Regarding the unnecessary Wait-Job, I agree with you. I actually didn't have it there initially and just put it out there for explicitness. 

So I copied your code and wrapped output statements on Receive-Job:

`Write-Host "-- Download Stopped."

Receive-Job $job;

Write-Host "-- Download Completed."`

The last output I see is "--Download Stopped." and the execution hangs here until I kill it.

And thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately my computer is still stuck on version 5.1.